# Why Swing frame isn't opening sometimes below I attached my code and anyone help me why is it happening?

Tags: java

Here I attach my code:
I'm now currently working on Music Player that I want to create so I coded on Swing framework. This code was working fine before adding two buttons named Previous button and Next Play Button. After adding those buttons Swing frame is not opening. I even tried commenting the newly added lines (Previous button and Next button) but that didn't help me.

```java
//Main Method
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class App {
    public static void main(String args[]){
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() { //To make Robust
            public void run(){  //Run Method
                new MainFrame();
            }
        });
    }
}

//Frame Method
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;
import java.awt.FlowLayout;

public class MainFrame extends JFrame {
    private JButton Play,Previous,Next;
    private JTextArea textArea;

    public MainFrame(){
        super("Hello World"); //Inherit that Jframe
        try {
            setLayout(new BorderLayout()); //Setting Layout
            setLayout(new FlowLayout());
            Play=new JButton("Play"); //Creating Object for Button
            Previous=new JButton("Previous");
            Next=new JButton("Next");
            textArea=new JTextArea();//Creating object for JTextArea
            Play.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent l) {
                    textArea.append("Song plays\n");//Print Song Plays
                }
            });
            Previous.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent l){
                    textArea.append("Previous Song\n");
                }
            });
            Next.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent l){
                    textArea.append("Next Song\n");
                }
            });
            //Adding TextArea and Buttons to Frame
            add(Play,FlowLayout.CENTER);//Adding to Frame
            add(textArea,FlowLayout.LEADING);//Adding to Frame
            add(Previous,FlowLayout.LEFT);
            add(Next,FlowLayout.RIGHT);
            setSize(800,800);//Size for Frame
            setResizable(true);
            setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
            setVisible(true);
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `setLayout(new BorderLayout()); setLayout(new FlowLayout());` why two different layouts?

Comment: Oracle has a helpful tutorial, [Creating a GUI With Swing](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/index.html).  Skip the Learning Swing with the NetBeans IDE section.  Pay particular attention to the [Laying Out Components Within a Container](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/index.html) section.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oracle has a helpful tutorial, [Creating a GUI With Swing](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/index.html).  Skip the Learning Swing with the NetBeans IDE section.  Pay particular attention to the [Laying Out Components Within a Container](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/index.html) section.

I went ahead and created the following GUI.

[image]

When creating a Swing GUI, you add Swing components to a `JPanel` or `JScrollPane`.  You add `JPanels` and/or `JScrollPanes` to your `JFrame`.  This helps keep your code organized.

Swing layout managers make creating a GUI simple.  You add Swing components to one or more `JPanels`, add the `JPanels` to the `JFrame`, and pack the `JFrame`.

The only "trick" I used was copying the preferred size of the largest `JButton` to the other `JButtons`.  This makes the GUI look better.

Here's the complete runnable code.

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.BorderFactory;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class MusicPlayer implements Runnable {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new MusicPlayer());
    }

    private JTextArea textArea;

    @Override
    public void run() {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Music Player");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        frame.add(createTextArea(), BorderLayout.CENTER);
        frame.add(createButtonPanel(), BorderLayout.SOUTH);

        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationByPlatform(true);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    private JScrollPane createTextArea() {
        JPanel panel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
        panel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));

        textArea = new JTextArea(10, 40);
        panel.add(textArea, BorderLayout.CENTER);

        JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(panel);

        return scrollPane;
    }

    private JPanel createButtonPanel() {
        JPanel panel = new JPanel(new FlowLayout());
        panel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));

        JButton previousButton = new JButton("Previous");
        previousButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
                textArea.append("Previous Song\n");
            }
        });
        panel.add(previousButton);

        JButton playButton = new JButton("Play");
        playButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
                textArea.append("Song plays\n");// Print Song Plays
            }
        });
        panel.add(playButton);

        JButton nextButton = new JButton("Next");
        nextButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
                textArea.append("Next Song\n");
            }
        });
        panel.add(nextButton);

        // Make the buttons the same size
        Dimension d = previousButton.getPreferredSize();
        playButton.setPreferredSize(d);
        nextButton.setPreferredSize(d);

        return panel;
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks brother very much appreciated!
and One more thing can you please clarify me  what's wrong with my code?

Comment: @K.J.Abishek: My answer explains what's wrong with your code.  No `JPanels`.  You extend a `JFrame`.  You size the `JFrame`.  All wrong.

Comment: Ok Sir Thankyou. Now I'm currently learning swing and working on my swing projects. I will surely get better in upcoming days. I seriously want to get better in java so please suggest me anything related java sir